# SKIMAGE DLL LOAD FAILURE _MAP_ARRAY

Tags: python, windows, dll, scikit-image

I installed skimage with comand pip.

when I try to run this code

```
from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity as ssim

import cv2
import numpy as np

before = cv2.imread('prima.jpg.jpg')
after = cv2.imread('seconda.jpg')

# Convert images to grayscale
before_gray = cv2.cvtColor(before, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
after_gray = cv2.cvtColor(after, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Compute SSIM between two images
(score, diff) = ssim(before_gray, after_gray, full=True)
print("Image similarity", score)
```

I have following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/a453769/Documents/2020/I&C/Dati/detect difference images/detect_diff_v2.py", line 2, in <module>
    from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity as ssim
  File "C:\Users\a453769\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\skimage\__init__.py", line 127, in <module>
    from .util.dtype import (img_as_float32,
  File "C:\Users\a453769\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\skimage\util\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from ._map_array import map_array
  File "C:\Users\a453769\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\skimage\util\_map_array.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ._remap import _map_array
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _remap: Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato.
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Maybe [that](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/4780) is useful to you. Unfortunately, I can't reproduce your problem. Code works like a charm.

Comment: I already chack and I tried this two suggestion   "pip install scikit-image==0.16" but this version give an error. the oldes version that i find is 0.18. and  I also tried "python -m pip install msvc-runtime" but i still have the same error